# No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached cant install packages

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, cuda

Hello I cant install any packages anymore.
I think this is because I run sudo apt-get upgrade.
If I try to install for exmaple xclip I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-cudart-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                        Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-cufft-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-curand-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-cusolver-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-cusparse-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-libraries-10-1 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-nvgraph-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-cusolver-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-cufft-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-curand-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-cusparse-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-npp-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-cudart-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-npp-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-nvgraph-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but 10.1.105-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried this command: sudo apt-get -f install
But then I got this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-cudart-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-10-1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cuda-cudart-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-10-1
10 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 26 not to upgrade.
362 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/354 MB of archives.
After this operation, 130 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 130208 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cudart-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cudart-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cudart-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-driver-dev-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-driver-dev-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-driver-dev-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cufft-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cufft-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-curand-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-curand-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cusolver-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cusolver-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cusparse-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cusparse-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvrtc-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvrtc-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-npp-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-npp-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvjpeg-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvjpeg-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-nvgraph-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvgraph-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvgraph-10-1 (10.1.243-1) over (10.1.105-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cusolver-10-1 10.1.105-1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cudart-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-driver-dev-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvjpeg-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-10-1_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In this post https://askubuntu.com/a/270225/618094 I read that I must delete old kernel files.

```
uname -r
```

gives me 4.4.0-87-generic

and

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-<TAB>
```

gives me:
linux-base
linux-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-firmware
linux-headers-4.4.0-87
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
linux-libc-dev

I dont really know what I should delete. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should use `df -h` to generate an overview of your disk space in case that was what caused either problem, and you should clarify whether you need anything *cuda*-related at all (maybe you can ignore the conflict by uninstalling those altogether).

Comment: this post solved it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1106499/618094