# CUDA can't be installed or uninstalled and dkpg can't install anything

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

When I do sudo apt --fix-broken install

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/00-cuda-cudart-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/01-cuda-driver-dev-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/02-cuda-cudart-dev-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/03-cuda-nvcc-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/04-cuda-cupti-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/05-cuda-cupti-dev-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/06-cuda-nvprof-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/07-cuda-nvtx-11-0_11.0.167-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/08-cuda-nvrtc-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/09-cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0_11.0.221-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/10-libcublas-11-0_11.2.0.252-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-6CZ1pM/11-libcublas-dev-11-0_11.2.0.252-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I do sudo apt install aptitude

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 : Depends: cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: cuda-nvprof-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: cuda-nvtx-11-0 (>= 11.0.167) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-compiler-11-0 : Depends: cuda-nvcc-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-libraries-11-0 : Depends: cuda-cudart-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: cuda-nvrtc-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcublas-11-0 (>= 11.2.0.252) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 : Depends: cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: cuda-driver-dev-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 (>= 11.0.221) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libcublas-dev-11-0 (>= 11.2.0.252) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-11-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: cuda-nvcc-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libcublas-dev-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: cuda-driver-dev-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to this

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

could not find cuda file inside /usr/local
however nvidia-smi saids CUDA version 11.4

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. I'm not posting this as an answer cause it's just a guess and I'm not sure if it fixes your problem but try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Thx for the reply but I forgot to mention that I also tried that

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution, it seems to be working now

[Upgrade or uninstall cuda to allow apt-get to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940582/upgrade-or-uninstall-cuda-to-allow-apt-get-to-work)

```
dpkg -l | grep cuda- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg --purge
df -h
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

An untested but similar answer that might work better...

sudo apt-get install $(dpkg -l | awk '/cuda-|nvidia-/ {print $2 "-"}' ) cuda

Basically, that allows all cuda and nvidia packages to be removed, and then installs cuda all in one step.  This allows apt-get to keep anything that doesn't conflict and remove what does.